# How do I get an Angularjs module and invoke .value on it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, configuration, module

I'm trying to use a vertxbus [module](https://github.com/knalli/angular-vertxbus). It's configuration is set using *.value*.
How do I update these configuration values from my 'appModule'?
To my understanding

```
angular.module('knalli.angular-vertxbus')
```

should return a reference to the module and *.value* should change the injected value.
I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bugbuster/xUV3g/) and here is the js used:

```
'use strict';

var testmodule = angular.module('TestModule', []).value('key', 'module').value('key', 'module2');
    testmodule.factory('MyService', ['key', function (key) {
    return key;
}]);

var module = angular.module('myApp', ['TestModule'])
.run(function () {
    testmodule.value('key', 'run1');
    angular.module('TestModule').value('key', 'run2');
}).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyService', 'key', function ($scope, MyService, key)      {
    $scope.value = MyService;
    $scope.key = key;
}]);
```

I would expect a result of *run2* or at least *run1* but *module2* is returned. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The actual idea behind `.value`, `.constant` or more generally `.config` is the possibility to *change how* the modules' components should constructed themselves.

In that case, the angular-translate's *vertxBus* component will invoke implicitly a SockJS instance which connects implicitly to a server. That means the configuration settings must be known *before* the application will be running. Because of this, there are two phases (see answer by Ilan Frumer): config and run.

However, because `.value` and `.config` are too static and could collide with other components, the angular module *angular-vertxbus* has an own provider for all the settings (since version 0.5: https://github.com/knalli/angular-vertxbus/releases/tag/v0.5.0).

Starting with *0.5*, this could be look like this:

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['knalli.vertx-eventbus']);
module.config(function(vertxEventBus) {
  vertxEventBus.useDebug(true).useUrlPath('/eventbus');
});
```

Just like the others, the provider is *only* available in the config-phase.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of angular-vertxbus

Answer (score 2):

#### $provide shorthands

Under the hood, `constant` & `value` & `service` & `factory` & `provider` are all shorthands for the `$provide` service which is available only during the configuration phase.

#### From angular.js documentation:

> A module is a collection of configuration and run blocks which get applied to the application during the bootstrap process. In its simplest form the module consist of collection of two kinds of blocks:
>
> 1. **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
> 2. **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.

#### your case:

You cannot register providers (in your case `value`) inside run blocks because they are only available during the **configuration phase**.

Read more about [modules](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) and [$provide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide)